# SQL remove duplicates from GROUP BY results

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following structure

```
sys_id(identity) | id | group_id | fld_id | val
-----------------------------------------------
```

I have a query

```
SELECT id,group_id,fld_id,val,COUNT(*)
FROM [DB_ALERT].[dbo].[DATATABLE]
GROUP BY id,group_id,fld_id,val
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

The resul set is like this

```
   ID  | group_id | fld_id | val| count(*)
__________________________________________
1000001| 1        | 1      | 23 | 2
1000003| 1        | 1      | 24 | 5
1000008| 1        | 1      | 14 | 4
```

Now in the result set I want to take only top 1 sys_id for each record and delete the others with same ID,Group,Fld and val (remove its dublicates). I know how to do this with cursors, but is there any way to do such operation in a single query?

Comment: Which is your database?

Comment: @techdo SQL Server 2008 r2

Comment: without cursor you can use Temporary Table and achieve that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
;with c as
(
    select *, row_number() over(partition by ID, Group, Fld, val order by ID, Group, Fld, val) as n
    from YouTable
)
delete from c
where n > 1
```

Comment: thanks, your query works. I doubt is it possible to make such query with standart SQL?